# I am getting special chars like &lt;p> in data and need to be formatted like rows

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have combined the data to an element but getting the data with special chars. Ex: In below xml, I am getting the values like `&lt;/p>&lt;p>&lt;span` in field:`<PSQ2>`.
This should be something like below: Need to know the reason for getting like this. In previous step, I am consolidating all the values into one using XSLT.

**Expected value of PSQ2:**

> Going beyond working hours to meet release timeline and other priority stuff.
> Skill set wise, I feel he is technically very well sound. Behavior wise, he is very friendly, make people feel like he is one of a family member. He advices people in both personal and professional ways. So far I didn't feel that he keeps double thoughts.
> He has shown good ability to analyze issues, make sound decisions and overcome problems. Always trying to improve code quality.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Entry
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:xdiff="urn:com.workday/esb/xdiff">
    <empid>123</empid>
    <name>Ramu</name>
    <title>Software Architect</title>
    <manager>Ahmed</manager>
    <tempno>2</tempno>
    <MRQ2>&lt;p>Excellent technical knowledge, problem solving capabilities, team player&lt;/p></MRQ2>
    <DRQ2/>
    <PSQ2>&lt;p>Going beyond working hours to meet release timeline and other priority stuff.&lt;/p>&lt;p>Skill set wise, I feel he is technically very well sound. Behavior wise, he is very friendly, make people feel like he is one of a family member. He advices people in both personal and professional ways. So far I didn&amp;#39;t feel that he keeps double thoughts.&lt;/p>&lt;p>&lt;span>He has shown good ability to analyze issues, make sound decisions and overcome problems. Always trying to improve code quality. &lt;/span>&lt;/p></PSQ2>
    <MRQ3>&lt;p>Evangelize the design thinking, groom junior devs, create technical vision&lt;/p></MRQ3>
    <DRQ3/>
    <PSQ3>&lt;p>Keep your momentum and work towards making Conga Platform UI a great success.&lt;/p>&lt;p>I think he should learn how to be visible till the highest level. Like, he does many better things, however, I feel his visibility is not that much. Credits which should come to him are somehow going to somebody else. So he should learn how to present what he has done in such a way so that all deserved credits goes to him, everything that he does are acknowledged by higher management. This can be possible through better communication and presentation skills.&lt;/p>&lt;p>He can learn and try out new technology and different tools which can provide alternative to solve a problem in the most ideal way.&lt;/p></PSQ3>
    <MRQ4>9</MRQ4>
    <DRQ4_Min/>
    <DRQ4_Max/>
    <DRQ4_Median/>
    <PSQ4_Min>8</PSQ4_Min>
    <PSQ4_Max>9</PSQ4_Max>
    <PSQ4_Median>8.0</PSQ4_Median>
    <MRQ6>9</MRQ6>
    <DRQ6_Min/>
    <DRQ6_Max/>
    <DRQ6_Median/>
    <PSQ6_Min>6</PSQ6_Min>
    <PSQ6_Max>8</PSQ6_Max>
    <PSQ6_Median>8.0</PSQ6_Median>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

To get that above xml, I used below XSLT for combining the data. I am not sure whether I am doing incorrectly in this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:xdiff="urn:com.workday/esb/xdiff"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Report_Data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data"/>
        </Report_Data>
    </xsl:template>
        
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:empid">

            <Report_Entry>
            <empid>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:empid"/>
            </empid>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:name"/>
                </name>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:title"/>
                </title>     
                <manager>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:manager"/>
                </manager>   
                <tempno>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:tempno"/>
                </tempno>                  
            <MRQ2>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Manager' and wd:questionno='2' ]">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </MRQ2>
            

                
                <DRQ2>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='2' ]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    
                </DRQ2>
                
            
            <PSQ2>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='2' ]">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </PSQ2>  
                
                <MRQ3>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Manager' and wd:questionno='3' ]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </MRQ3>
                
                
                
                <DRQ3>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='3' ]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    
                </DRQ3>
                
                
                <PSQ3>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='3' ]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </PSQ3> 
                
                <MRQ4>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Manager' and wd:questionno='4' ]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </MRQ4>
                
                
                
                <DRQ4_Min>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='4']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </DRQ4_Min>
                
                <DRQ4_Max>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='4']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </DRQ4_Max>
                
                <DRQ4_Median>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='4']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="length" select="last()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$pos = floor($length div 2) + 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:response),'#.###')"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </DRQ4_Median>
                
                
                <PSQ4_Min>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='4']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </PSQ4_Min>
                
                <PSQ4_Max>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='4']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </PSQ4_Max>
                
                <PSQ4_Median>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='4']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="length" select="last()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$pos = floor($length div 2) + 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:response),'#.###')"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </PSQ4_Median> 
            
                <MRQ6>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Manager' and wd:questionno='6' ]">
                        <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </MRQ6>
                
                
                
                <DRQ6_Min>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='6']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </DRQ6_Min>
                
                <DRQ6_Max>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='6']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </DRQ6_Max>
                
                <DRQ6_Median>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Direct Report' and wd:questionno='6']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="length" select="last()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$pos = floor($length div 2) + 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:response),'#.###')"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </DRQ6_Median>
                
                
                <PSQ6_Min>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='6']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </PSQ6_Min>
                
                <PSQ6_Max>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='6']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="wd:response"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </PSQ6_Max>
                
                <PSQ6_Median>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[wd:category = 'Peer/Stakeholder' and wd:questionno='6']">
                        <xsl:sort select="wd:response" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="length" select="last()"/>
                        <xsl:if test="$pos = floor($length div 2) + 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(wd:response),'#.###')"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>                    
                </PSQ6_Median> 
            
            </Report_Entry>
            
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your input contains the literal strings `&lt;p>` and `>&lt;/p>` and other escaped markup. Your XSLT (which you don't show) is probably copying the original text. Removing the markup will be difficult in XSLT 2.0 (might be easier in XSLT 3.0).

Comment: The input is an html fragment that was escaped to produce a valid XML. Needs to be parsed to extract text only.

Comment: XML and HTML "sometimes" can be parse with library meant for the other.  In most cases you need to parse Xml with a XML library and HTML with an HTML library.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. I posted my XSLT as well by using that I am getting the xml data with special chars. I am not sure where I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: You are not doing anything incorrectly. Your data provider is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<PSQ2>&lt;p>Going beyond working hours to meet release timeline and other priority stuff.&lt;/p>&lt;p>Skill set wise, I feel he is technically very well sound. Behavior wise, he is very friendly, make people feel like he is one of a family member. He advices people in both personal and professional ways. So far I didn&amp;#39;t feel that he keeps double thoughts.&lt;/p>&lt;p>&lt;span>He has shown good ability to analyze issues, make sound decisions and overcome problems. Always trying to improve code quality. &lt;/span>&lt;/p></PSQ2>
```

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="PSQ2">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(.)/p" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>Going beyond working hours to meet release timeline and other priority stuff. Skill set wise, I feel he is technically very well sound. Behavior wise, he is very friendly, make people feel like he is one of a family member. He advices people in both personal and professional ways. So far I didn't feel that he keeps double thoughts. He has shown good ability to analyze issues, make sound decisions and overcome problems. Always trying to improve code quality. </result>
```

The `parse-xml-fragment()`function requires a processor that supports XSLT 3.0. Without this, it will be **much** more difficult to extract the text from the escaped markup.

---

### Added:

Once you have parsed the escaped markup as XML, you can process it as XML in any way you like - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="PSQ2">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="parse-xml-fragment(.)/p">
            <xsl:number format="1. "/>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

would produce:

```
<result>1. Going beyond working hours to meet release timeline and other priority stuff.
2. Skill set wise, I feel he is technically very well sound. Behavior wise, he is very friendly, make people feel like he is one of a family member. He advices people in both personal and professional ways. So far I didn't feel that he keeps double thoughts.
3. He has shown good ability to analyze issues, make sound decisions and overcome problems. Always trying to improve code quality. 
</result>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps me. Can we show data like paragraph based on your results or seq number. I mean showing the data in next line after 1st statement. Ex: 1. Going beyond working hours to meet release timeline and other priority stuff.
2. Skill set wise, I feel he is technically very well sound. Behavior wise, he is very friendly, make people feel like he is one of a family member. He advices people in both personal and professional ways. So far I didn't feel that he keeps double thoughts.
3. He has shown good ability to analyze issues, make sound decisions and overcome probl.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching this. Is there anyway that we randomly display the statements (instead of our order). Ex: Skill set wise statement is the first one. 2nd: He has shown good quality statement and 3rd: Going forward working statement. Can this be possible to keep randomly?

Comment: Use `random-number-generator(current-dateTime())?permute(parse-xml-fragment(.)/p)`

Comment: Hi Martin, I am looking for picking up the statement randomly (not number generator). ex: Skill set wise statement is the first one. 2nd: He has shown good quality statement and 3rd: Going forward working statement

Comment: @Buddi, the `permute` function will pick a random permutation of the sequence passed in which in your case is the sequence of `parse-xml-fragment(.)/p`.

Comment: @Buddi Please do not keep extending your question to unrelated topics. If necessary, ask a new one.